# Que choisir, « de plus » ou « en plus » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, choix-de-mot

Faut-il préférer :

> Attend un peu, j'ai quelque chose de plus pour toi.

ou

> Attend un peu, j'ai quelque chose en plus pour toi.

Y a-t-il une différence de sens ?

Comment: Il faudrait une phrase entière (ou plus de contexte) pour juger. L'usage dépend du sens que tu veux donner…

Comment: This is correct in these examples. However, this would be wrong if you used "En plus, ..." instead of "De plus, ...".

Comment: @wok: right, my question is rather to know if there is a difference in this very context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Les deux sont équivalents.

L'expression *de plus* est généralement considérée comme plus distinguée, et est donc préférable dans un contexte formel.

Comment: Je ne suis pas vraiment d'accord. J'ai l'impression qu'il y a une nuance de sens, et pas seulement de niveau de langue. Il y a des phrases ou je préfère *de plus* et des phrases ou je préfère *en plus*, mais je ne trouve pas de bon critère pour les distinguer.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' — Même si ce n'est pas évident pour l'exemple cité, peut-être “de plus” renverrait à un sentiment, une attitude, un souhait, une idée positive : « … il y a déjà cela, *de plus*, on aimerait… » en opposition à « reproche 1, reproche 2, *en plus* [pour finir au summum] reproche 3. »

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' … dialogue possible :  « — Il y a … [et | ***,***] *de plus* … — Non seulement … mais *en plus* …  »

Answer (score 2):

Dans le premier exemple il est sous entendu qu'on rajoute quelque chose à autre chose (qui est probablement cité dans la phrase précédente). On se concentre sur le fait que c'est un bonus/rajout.

Dans le second exemple *quelque chose en plus* est pris comme un ensemble. L’intérêt se porte sur cette chose sans insister sur ce à quoi elle vient s'ajouter.

Pour résumer tu dis pratiquement la même chose: dans la première phrase tu veux mettre l'accent sur le fait que c'est en plus de ce qu'il y avait auparavant, dans la seconde tu ramènes plus l'attention de ton interlocuteur sur la teneur de ce que tu offres.